# Nested XPath within XPath

Tags: django, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to extract various general data from websites, such as titles, h1, h2, img src and alts. I've gotten it working just fine for titles, h1 and h2s. But I've ran into some issues when extracting the src and alts.

I know that I can extract srcs and alts with syntax like this(src in this case):

```
 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 for img in hxs.select('//img/@src').extract():
```

My problem is that I want to loop over each image found, and then save the src and alts to different models.

These are my models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    src = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)

class Alt(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
for img in hxs.select('//img').extract():
    hxs2 = HtmlXPathSelector(img)
    try:
        i = Image(page=page, src=hxs2.select('//img/@src'))
        i.save()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        a = Alt(image=i, text=hxs2.select('//img/@alt'))
        a.save()
    except:
        pass
```

This doesn't really work. I'm getting the following error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'unicode' object
```

My question is whether this is a good approach, or I should try something else? Possibly regex, since I'll be having a very defined set of html each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.select()` already returns a list of `HtmlXPathSelector`s (See [Nesting selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#nesting-selectors)) so
I think you want something like this:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
for img in hxs.select('//img'):
    try:
        i = Image(page=page, src=img.select('@src').extract()[0])
        i.save()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        a = Alt(image=i, text=img.select('@alt').extract()[0])
        a.save()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Shame on me for not reading the documentation properly. I missed the part that excluding .extract() returned HtmmlXPathSelectors.